Certainty for the existence of tomorrow?
The title might not be the best but it was the best I could do. The question presses on the matter of continuity of time and the necessity of existence as a connected metaphysical phenomena.
Just like the existence of space and time had to be and consecutively  the big bang had to happen, specifically just like there is "something instead of nothing", why couldn't the exact opposite happen? At any time?
Other than the existence of the past what evidence do we have that any future will exist. Can we say with a 100% certainty that because all this time existence "was", that will always be the case, what I am trying to get at is just like everything exists matter, space, time couldn't everything stop existing at any time. Do we have any concrete evidence "everything" won't 'be' the very next picosecond or whatever interval of time you choose to use?
"Just because something didn't happen in the past doesn't mean it won't happen in the future" - is this a logically correct assumption?
Edit: From the answers so far, it kind of seems like I am asking about the Earth not existing, but I want to make it clear that I am asking about the universe and space and time and everything along with it. The question might be absurd, but I just want to point out that there is a scientific hypothesis that actually supports my frustration, it is said that at any point in time if the expansion of space is greater than the force exerted by the gravitational pull of the universe that the fabric of space time could tear which I think is absolutely absurd given the fact that we don't know the total gravity of the whole universe and the 'threshold of expansion of space time' space time could rip apart and reality could stop existing the very next second and this is the smallest hypothesis that I am putting forth to support my question.

No certainty al all: maybe this night the universe will disappear...

"beng-and-time" tag is about Heidegger's book, I suppose.

"existence of the past" - how sure are you about THAT?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I think you are right, I tried fixing it.

How can we be sure something is happening now?

@ScottRowe I don't know what your definition of "now" is but evidence of the senses. Justification by sense. We can be sure something happened in the past because of evidence of memory, but the future it not only takes evidence of memory but also the projection (faith) of the past to happen yet again. Faith in the "consistency of existence".

It's the best we can do, I suppose.

Comment to edit about space-time ripping: I mean, we don't know enough to rule it out. If there was a Big Rip, then all the stuff we are familiar with might end up superluminally far apart. When I was a kid in school I put some alcohol on a microscope slide with a paramecium on it and watched as the cell membrane ruptured and the living stuff flowed out, still moving, then stopped moving as it dispersed. Perhaps something like that?

Maybe. But we are comparing reality, space and time to a bacteria here, I think the scale of difference is "astronomical". Comparing something that can be studied, controlled and manipulated to something we even remotely know of and are actually controlled by. Extremely different

We can use the stars and planets to plot the trajectory (past and future) of the Earth in a 3d Euclidian geometry space.
We can point along that trajectory and say "On this day the Earth was here"... and "on this day it was here" and to points in the future... "on this future date it will be here".
The Sun's trajectory is almost the same as Earth's rotational axis.  So, our joined path (the whole solar system) is heading towards the North Star (Polaris).
If you point a camera at Polaris and set it to long exposure, it creates an image called "star trails".  They create a kind of "virtual tunnel" visually.
That "virtual tunnel" serves as a pretty good stand-in for the path of Earth's future.  (there is a lot of looping and circling in the path... but inevitably it heads... "thataway" into the future:

We can do it so accurately that we know now that a particular meteor is going to pass between Earth and the moons orbit months from now.
Remember how tiny humans are... all put together the Earth out-masses us 12 trillion to one.
Some predict the position of planets by months.
I think as long as you look both ways when crossong roads, and are in decent health... tomorrow is certain.

Right, but ants vastly outmass humans also.

@ScottRowe I think "used to" and that we caught up.  We have gained a lot of weight since I was born (not that I personally have much responsibility for that)... but we've gone from 3 million to 8 million.  Ants haven't changed much.  And I think we about equal them now.    Trees are the real winners, mass wise.  But all of the above... are "along for the ride".  Really Earth wins by such a margin that nuttin else much matters.

+1 I understand what you are saying and I know how you are cosmologically explaining that the existence of Earth through time and space is very imminent and that we have a solid understanding so we know, but my question is on a ontological and metaphysical level, I am asking just like how the big bang occurred and the universe unfolded according to the laws of nature what if the laws of nature and space break down or simply stop existing at any point. The very fabric of space and time tear or just stopped 'being'.

@Howwhye It seems to me (this doesn't make it a "necessarily so" claim)... that we have observations of billions of years of information of "consistent similar progression of events" where situations parallel ours.... meaning... within the aged/ageable observations of celestial events... nothing screams "That place acted way differently than that other place"... everything seems to point to a consistent predictable progression... billions of years worth.  So we don't have to appeal to faith or trust... we can appeal to "cohesion with billions of years of observation".  I suggest.

@Howwhye if you look at the history of predictions of doom (theres a list on wikipedia)... you notice predictions tend to be closely related to the duration of existence of the claimant.  Ignoring the arbitrariness of their existence within time.  Showing their fears to be largely ego driven / self-referential.  If we imagine an unravelling of reality might occur in 46 trillion years.. it might be objective.  If we fear reality unravelling next Tuesday, or anytime within our brief flash of existence... it is likely we are being ego-biased.  I suggest.

@Howwhye https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dates_predicted_for_apocalyptic_events ... which is why we need to be extra skeptical if our thoughts drift in such a direction.  (again, this is my suggestion).

Quote from linked Wikipedia article: "Polls conducted in 2012 across 20 countries found over 14% of people believe the world will end in their lifetime, with percentages ranging from 6% of people in France to 22% in the US and Turkey. Belief in the apocalypse is observed to be most prevalent in people with lower rates of education, lower household incomes, and those under the age of 35. In the UK in 2015, 23% of the general public believed the apocalypse was likely to occur in their lifetime, compared to 10% of experts from the Global Challenges Foundation."

@AlistairRiddoch I want to make it clear I am no doomsayer of any sorts and my question itself doesn't intentionally set an accurate date or anything like that of any sorts, if you can see I am literally establishing a completely arbitrary point in time in my question i.e., even down to a picosecond and I want you to understand that this was a complete thought experiment to show that we truly don't know a lot of things down to the basics of fundamental reality and a lot of it is assumption that seems to be very consistent but might not be forever, not necessarily, we just don't know

@AlistairRiddoch It seems to me that you point out Polaris but I want to say that the light we receive from that star doesn't mean a thing, we are looking at the 'Polaris' from the Past most of the stars we see are not in their current states, so the existence of their lights doesn't mean a ton.  A lot of light years away. I also want to add that we use the concept of space-time as a 'fabric' but don't know anything about its properties and why it expands, don't know anything about dark energy/cosmological constant that is causing the expansion....

@AlistairRiddoch ....thus with the possibility of a hypothetical tear all around space simultaneously and instantly the existence of the display of these other stars and Polaris will mean nothing.

@Howwhye Academic exercises are okely dokely... its a common theme within the fabric of society.  an entire genre of movies.  Note that Polaris is arbitrary, and simply stands as the current almost-heading of the solar system.. it changes over time.  it is just the temporary... "whats at the end of the tunnel that depicts Earth's future travel plans.

@Howwhye Yes... comes down to nature of fundamental reality.  I expect we will determine that "energy" is actually physically embodied.  And that the mechanical host is composed of immutable individual components... which are therefor timeless.  Then we will know that no rip cometh.  If we confirm final knowledge of fundamental reality, we can draw firm conclusions about such things.  I might be wrong, but expect not.  The upside is, if I am right about reality, then I am right about the absence of impending doom.  Cheers.  A.

@AlistairRiddoch I don't know what you mean if you are right about reality if you are talking about your theory then your theory must bring forth the grand unification theory and explain every observation including dark matter and dark energy, it also must deal with the quantization of space and time and how that fits into the bigger picture of current quantum mechanics conceptions and also must be able to unite relativity and quantum mechanics all these should be met before one supposes one is right about reality!

@Howwhye Yes.  But.  That I may be wrong is why I don't push it as a reason to expect a tomorrow.  Going with "we are all on Earth and along for the ride" and that "history, billions of years of evidence, leads to the conclusion of consistency and persistency".  AND also not it is noteable that... the origins of doomsday scenarios and the bulk of the ones made have been religious in nature and based on unknowns, rather than any evidence of anything of the sort being impending...... AND... only if insisting that because "we" don't know, we should entertain the "possibility"... then...

@Howwhye ... THEN under those conditions, I would suggest... I don't concede to "we dont know".  I might, but cannot claim necessarily so.  There's a difference.  I will suggest there is not a more plausible suggestion regarding the composition of reality.


The question presses on the matter of continuity of time and the necessity of existence as a connected metaphysical phenomena.

There is no logical requirement (that I can think of) for time/existence not to end, or have started, at some "point".
Incidentally, I rather find your framing a bit objectionable: while there is no a priori guarantee that time and our Universe with it will not suddendly end, that "future" like "past" exist here and now is as true and immediate as that time here and now is "passing" at all.

"Just because something didn't happen in the past doesn't mean it won't happen in the future" - is this a logically correct assumption?

Of some things we do know that they cannot, or cannot but, happen, in so far as we believe in a continuity of the laws of nature (e.g. that gravity wouldn't stop working), but also and more fundamentally in the intrinsic rationality of the Universe.  If we do.

I have edited my question and I hope my framing becomes a little bit more acceptable.

@Howwhye  You have not changed it.  I meant: you say "that any future will exist", but it is not the persistence of "future" but rather that of "time" that is/may be in question.  Anyway, it's more of a marginal point.

I do not think that any physicist or philosopher can guarantee that tomorrow will exist, and if he calculates that tomorrow must exist by a series of known scientific evidence, he cannot answer the question: how can we prove that the next day will exist at the end of the universe?
Because to answer this question, he must first prove that the universe has no end, and he must also answer: how can you prove that the universe existed the day before the Big Bang?

+1 Great answer, this is what I was expecting for someone to respond and I think the exact same! Thank you1

It depends on your point of view. I am 100% certain that the Universe won't disappear overnight. I say that because the idea of the Universe disappearing seems utterly without justification, and conflicts with all we know about conservation laws in physics. On the other hand, people who believe the Universe is a computer simulation might be entirely content to entertain the possibility that the simulation might be switched off. It is up to you to form your own view. However, what I would say is that assuming something extraordinary with no shred of justification is possibly a sign of madness, so you might consider booking an early appointment with a local phrenologist to have your bumps carefully felt.

Don't look up, Marco!

Haha, I am afraid my "electrical speech machine" doesn't seem to be working with phone calls in the 1700s, that appointment must wait until I get my time machine.

+1 For the effort. Conservation laws didn't necessarily hold for the beginning of energy and matter (the big bang - beginning of the universe), there was a beginning and matter and energy were created which does defy the conservative laws of matter and energy.

Thanks for taking the answer in good spirit! +1. I remember reading some suggestion that conservation laws weren't violated by the Big Bang, because there's as much positive energy as negative, so the two add up to zero. I don't know if that's fallen out of favour now.

I really don't understand the argument that there was positive and negative energy before the beginning of time and space? How can there even be energy let alone positive and negative ones

No, the argument was that there was zero energy before the Big Bang and there is zero energy now.

So...? What does that mean? It is not doing anything to explain the appearance of phenomena or the necessity of existence; if there was zero energy before why did it not stay that way, huh?

@Howwhye it got bored?

@ScottRowe When in doubt... Anthropomorphism, classic!

@Howwhye a bunch of adolescent hooligan universes with nothing to do on a Saturday eon... "It blowed up REAL good!"

@Howwhye a diety in elementary school puts some antimatter on the 'brane that supports this universe... Oops!

@ScottRowe These anthropomorphisms are getting funnier by the moment
